# Why GroupMargin.Symbol is an empty string for all groups in GroupsRequest() list?

Tags: metatrader4

Hi after calling **`GroupsRequest()`** I get a list of all the user groups, but why on all of them, in their SecMargins list, all Symbol properties of GroupMargin objects are empty strings?

Should I call some other function to get the list of symobls and margins for a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupsRequest` is a lightweight method. If you want to get full information, you should use `CfgRequestGroup`. However this method requires more permissions.

Comment: Sysadmin assures me I have all the permissions, Do I need to call some other function to elevate permission for CfgRequesGroup, since it also returns empty strings for all Symbol strings in the SecMargins properity

Comment: Never mind, the team didn't setup the our dev server demo groups, they didn't add symbols to the groups. Thanks for the response